# Docker-compose: Copying files from local env to EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

Hello I have a configuration that builds docker containers for a flask app and a mysql instance.

I create a new VM with

`docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --....... production`

and then (after setting the correct environment)

`docker-compose build` -> `docker-compose up -d`

The problem is that all these happen whilst CWD is a local repo with the files I need. It turns out these files are not copied over.

I have looked at [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) and [docker scp](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/scp/) but it seems they do not solve the problem. E.g. with SCP I cannot reference the specific machine I need to copy the repo over (xow_web_1)

Here is the `.yml`

```
web:
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - .:/xow
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - db
  hostname: xowflask
  command: python xow.py
db:
  restart: always
  hostname: xowmysql
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepasswordhere
    MYSQL_DATABASE: somedatabase
data:
  restart: always
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
     - /var/lib/mysql
  command: "true"
```

How would be the most appropriate way to solve this? Is `docker-compose` the right approach? Looks awesome, but it doesn't solve an issue like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we solved it in our organization is by using the `COPY` command to copy all of the data in the folder to the container.
For example, copying all of the files from the current dir to the container /src folder will look like this -

```
### Copy Code
COPY . /src
```

It looks like you should add this line into the `web` container in your docker-compose configuration.